# Firefox extension to increase speed on vimeo and Youtube videos

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to build a Firefox extension to increase the speed of videos on Vimeo and Youtube.

**Without** an extension, I am able to **succesfully** do that with (e.g., 3 times the normal speed):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate = 3
```

I just need to run that on the Firefox Web Console  (control+shift+k).

In order to build this, I am following the great tutorial provided by Mozilla on the [*Your First Extension*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension) and I was able to successfully replicate what was shown on the tutorial.

After repeating the lesson, I tried some small tweaks.

I did this color change on the `borderify.js` file. This script has direct access to the webpage:

```
document.body.style.border = "50px solid yellow";
```

And on the `manifest.json` I changed the *matches* values to get **youtube** and **vimeo** domains/sub-domains:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Borderify",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Adds a red border to all webpages matching mozilla.org.",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*.youtube.com/*",
        "*://*.vimeo.com/*",
      ],
      "js": [
        "borderify.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My doubts are:

1 - The implementation was able to change the color of the Vimeo pages:

[image]

However, the color change ** does not happen** on Youtube.

Why does that happen?
Do I need to write something on the `.js` file to override Youtube's CSS/HTML source?
Why Youtube and Vimeo behave in a different way?

2 - This color tweak was just a small iteration to see if was doing things right. What I  really want to do is speed up the videos by 3x the normal speed.

Hence, I changed my script on `borderify.js` to **really** use the code I mentioned above:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate = 3
//document.body.style.border = "50px solid yellow";
```

Despite the fact that this single line of code work on my console browser, it does not work on the firefox extension.

Different from the yellow sidebar, this command does not work either on Vimeo or Youtube.

Why does that happen? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI - On most YouTube videos, having a `playbackRate` greater than 3 results in the audio cutting out.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, nice. I did not know that. Thanks for sharing. However, my implementation above does not work even with 3 or 2 (which is already built-in)